# How to Reschedule the Schedule Script in Netsuite using SuiteScript 2.0 version

Tags: javascript, scheduled-tasks, netsuite, suitescript

I want to **reschedule the schedule script** , when the schedule script usage before hitting the governor limits. schedule script in Netsuite has 10,000 units. **In SuiteScript 1.0 version, rescheduling is acheived by "nlapiScheduleScript() api " but in SuiteScript 2.0 version how to reschedule the script.**

help me to achieve this,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `N/task` and `N/runtime` modules have what you're looking for. You'll use `N/task` to do the rescheduling, and `N/runtime` to get the current script info.

Without your exact code I can't give a very specific example, but your scheduled script will end up looking generally something like:

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['N/task', 'N/runtime'], function(task, runtime) {

    /**
     * Reschedules the current script and returns the ID of the reschedule task
     */
    function rescheduleCurrentScript() {
        var scheduledScriptTask = task.create({
            taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT
        });
        scheduledScriptTask.scriptId = runtime.getCurrentScript().id;
        scheduledScriptTask.deploymentId = runtime.getCurrentScript().deploymentId;
        return scheduledScriptTask.submit();
    }

    function execute(context) {

        // Do stuff...

        while(...) {
            // Do processing in loop

            // Check remaining usage and reschedule if necessary
            if (runtime.getCurrentScript().getRemainingUsage() < 100) {
                var taskId = rescheduleCurrentScript();
                log.audit("Rescheduling status: " + task.checkStatus(taskId));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        execute: execute
    };
});
```

Comment: Does this also allow for the script to leave off at the same point in execution? For example, if I am looping through the results of a saved search in a scheduled script, can this method resume the scheduled script at the same result in the saved search where the script left off? Or will it start at the first result of the saved search?

Comment: Whenever you reschedule a Scheduled Script, you need to manage resuming where it left off. This is typically accomplished by sorting the results by internal ID, storing the last processed ID, and filtering your search for internal IDs greater than the last processed.

Comment: Where's the safest place to store that Last Processed ID?

Comment: Typically stored in a Script Parameter.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but all I can see is where to *get* a Script parameter: https://debugger.na2.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4296359529.html#bridgehead_4296459957

Comment: @Dr.Ernie - You would need to create this parameter on your script deployment to both store the value and get in your script runs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like scheduledScriptTask.submit() is returning null.

```
var taskId = rescheduleCurrentScript();
```

taskId above returns null when logged. 
Is it possibly a bug in NetSuite side?

Comment: Nope. It is in the docs: A scheduled script can be submitted for processing only if there is no unfinished scheduled script task for the same script ID and script deployment ID. Therefore, if a scheduled script resubmits itself, the actual resubmit does not occur until the current execution completes. This delay is necessary to avoid the existence of two unfinished tasks for the same deployment of the same script. For this reason, if a scheduled script uses the submit() method to resubmit itself, then at runtime, no task ID is returned when the scheduled script is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good for occasional yields. In addition to this if you know you are going to often breach the governance limits you may want to consider a [Map/Reduce script](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4387799161.htmlh) instead as it has yielding/resuming built in.